# PHP Sort Mega-Array by Value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am looking for some advices how could I sort this kind of Array by 'variant_name' key.

Because Array is really huge I minified it to the looking result state.

```
    ...
    $filter[2413][1][81][sub_id] = 1;
    $filter[2413][1][81][variant_id] = 81;
    $filter[2413][1][81][variant_name] = 'Banana';

    $filter[2413][2][87][sub_id] = 2;
    $filter[2413][2][87][variant_id] = 87;
    $filter[2413][2][87][variant_name] = 'Apple';

    $filter[2413][3][32][sub_id] = 3;
    $filter[2413][3][32][variant_id] = 32;
    $filter[2413][3][32][variant_name] = 'Carrot';
    ...
```

Keys `$filter[x][x][x]` are not sequential.

I have tried the sort function I used before but it doesn't work with this kind of Array:

```
function array_sort_by_column(&$arr, $col, $dir = SORT_ASC) {
    $sort_col = array();
    foreach ($arr as $key=> $row) {
        $sort_col[$key] = $row[$col];
    }
    array_multisort($sort_col, $dir, $arr);
}
array_sort_by_column($filter[][][], 'variant_name');
```

My target is modify array by sorting 'variant_name' to 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Carrot' accordingly keeping the array structure.

Comment: usort() is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a working code tested from given examples.

Note that my codes still can be optimized, etc. Just take it as my advice.

TL;DR = Use `usort()`.

```
function mySort($a,$b)
{
    $av = "";
    $bv = "";

    foreach($a as $ak)
        $av = $ak['variant_name'];

    foreach($b as $bk)
        $bv = $bk['variant_name'];

    if($av[0] < $bv[0])
        return false;
    else return true;
}
```

How to use it? You have to specify which first level array to sort.

```
usort($filter['2413'],"mySort");
```

Then the result I got is:

```
Array
(
    [2413] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [87] => Array
            (
                [sub_id] => 2
                [variant_id] => 87
                [variant_name] => Apple
            )
        )

        [1] => Array
        (
            [81] => Array
            (
                [sub_id] => 1
                [variant_id] => 81
                [variant_name] => Banana
            )
        )

        [2] => Array
        (
            [32] => Array
            (
                [sub_id] => 3
                [variant_id] => 32
                [variant_name] => Carrot
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Craftein, [sub_id]'s Value doesn't correspond to original $filter[filter_id][sub_id] (second) key.

Comment: i don't think that's possible. when you change their order by sorting, you'd inevitably will change their keys.